# Only first line gets printed from a file. Using forks and pipes

Tags: c, pipe

I'm trying to make this print multiple lines of a file with spaces replaced with * and everything translated to uppercase. This is supposed be done through pipes and forks. Why is it that only the first line gets printed.

```
void writer(int inpipe)
{
    char read_msg[BUFFER_SIZE];
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];
    read(inpipe, read_msg, BUFFER_SIZE);
    printf("%s\n",read_msg);
    return;
}

void p2(int inpipe)
{
    char read_msg[BUFFER_SIZE];

    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];
    if(pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("Pipe error");
        return;
    }

    pid = fork();
    if(pid<0) {  //error
        perror("Fork Failed");
        return;
    }
    else if(pid==0) { //child
        close(fd[1]);
        writer(fd[0]);
        close(fd[0]);
        return;
    }
    else {  //parent, p2()
        read(inpipe, read_msg, BUFFER_SIZE);
        int i = 0;
        while (read_msg[i] != '\0') {
            read_msg[i] = toupper(read_msg[i]);
            i++;
        }
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1],read_msg,(unsigned long)(strlen(read_msg)+1));
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    return;
}

void p1(int inpipe)
{
    char read_msg[BUFFER_SIZE];

    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];
    if(pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("Pipe error");
        return;
    }

    pid = fork();
    if(pid<0) {  //error
        perror("Fork Failed");
        return;
    }
    else if(pid==0) { //child
        close(fd[1]);
        p2(fd[0]);
        close(fd[0]);
        return;
    }
    else {  //parent, p1()
        read(inpipe, read_msg, BUFFER_SIZE);
        int i = 0;
        while (read_msg[i] != '\0') {
            if ((read_msg[i] == ' '))
                read_msg[i] = '*';
            i++;
        }
        //printf("%s\n",read_msg);
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1],read_msg,(unsigned long)(strlen(read_msg)+1));
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];

    if(pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("Pipe error");
        return 1;
    }
    pid = fork();
    if(argv[1] != NULL) {
        char const* const fileName = argv[1];
        FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");
        char line[BUFFER_SIZE];

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)){
            if(pid<0) {  //error
                perror("Fork Failed");
                return 1;
            }
            else if(pid==0) { //child
                close(fd[1]);
                p1(fd[0]);
                close(fd[0]);
            }
            else {  //parent, main(), reader
                //reading from the file and put it into the pipe[1]
                close(fd[0]);
                write(fd[1],line,strlen(line)+1);
                close(fd[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
        printf("No file detected.\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you need a total redesign. You open your pipes once in `main()` before the `fork()`, and them attempt to close them every single time you read a line from your file. If you were checking the returns from your system calls like you should be, you'd be seeing failures left, right and center. If you don't close them, though, the way you have your `read()` calls written will make them read too much and throw away input you need. You never `wait()` for your children. Unfortunately, this code is just not salvageable, you need a completely different strategy.

Comment: Not to mention, at the first iteration, you already have two processes, and via `p1()` your child ends up creating two more. None of these processes ever terminate, so they'll just `return` and go back through the loop. Three of them will *each* then create a further two processes on the second line of the file, so you'll have 10. Nine of them will create a further two processes on the third line, so you'll have 28. Even if it worked, you wouldn't get very far through your file before you're printing each line thousands and thousands of times while forkbombing your own system.